# Need help implementing finite difference Beam Propagation Method to Solve 2-D Helmholtz equation

Tags: finite-difference, matlab, computational-physics

I am trying to implement beam propagtion method in a two-dimensional lattice to solve Helmholtz equation by following the scheme given [this](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11082-006-0019-4) paper. I am using Matlab for implementation.

The expected results are:

1. For ordered Lattice:

[image]

2. For disordered lattice:

[image]

There is localization in the disordered lattice due to Anderson Localization.

Now here's my attempt at reproducing these results:
First, I define lattice parameters and constants.

```
    clear all;
    close All;
    
    %constants---------------------------------------------%
    lambda = 1e-6; % wavelength in micrometer
    k_0 = 2*pi/lambda;
    n_r = 1.46; %constant refractive index
    
    %------------------------------------------------------%
    N_x = 100; %steps along x
    
    x1 = -350e-6;
    x2 = 350e-6;
    delta_x = (x2-x1)/(N_x);
    x = linspace(x1,x2-delta_x,N_x); %steps along x
   
    z1 = 0;
    z2 = 7e-3;
    delta_z = 0.2e-6;
    N_z = int32((z2-z1)/delta_z);%number of steps along z
    z = linspace(z1,z2-delta_z,N_z);
```

Now there since this paper aims to reduce the algebra of finite difference method into simple matrix operations, the $\delta_x^2$ is simply given by the $D_x$ matrix which is tridiagonal and has -2 on its primary diagonal and 1 on both the sub diagonals. In Matlab, I have written

```
D_x = diag(-2*ones(1,N_x)) + diag(1*ones(1,N_x-1),1) + diag(1*ones(1,N_x-1),-1);
```

There is an $S$ operator. I am not sure of its functionality other than that it is used to define the $P$ matrix used in the step calculation $\phi(z+\Delta z) = PQP \phi(z)$. The $S$ operator is defined as: $$S = k_0^2 n_r^2 I + \frac{1}{\Delta_2} \left( D_x-\frac{1}{12} D_x^2+\frac{1}{90} D_x^2-\frac{1}{560} D_x^2 \right)$$, which I defined the code as:

```
S = (k_0^2)*(n_r^2)*eye(N_x)+(1/(delta_x^2))*(D_x-((1/12)*D_x^2)+((1/90)*D_x^3)-((1/560)*D_x^4));
```

The elements of $P$ operator is defined as:

```
P_11 = cos(sqrtm(S)*delta_z/2);
P_12 = (sin(sqrtm(S)*delta_z/2))/sqrtm(S); 
P_21 = -sqrtm(S)*sin(sqrtm(S)*delta_z/2)/sqrtm(S);
P_22 = cos(sqrtm(S)*delta_z/2);
```

**I am confused about defining the R  matrix part, which corresponds to the lattics structure**. In the paper, it is mentioned to specify the refractive index by specifying the field at different nodes $x_j$, at which the refractive index is defined as $n_j^2(z) = n^2(x_j,z)$. Then this array is assigned to the diagonal of $R$ matrix such that $R_{jj}(z) = n^2(x_j,z)$. This matrix is used in defining the $Q$ matrix which is given by $$
\begin{bmatrix}
 I & 0 \\
 -k_0^2 R(z) \Delta_z & I\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I define $R$ matrix in my code as follows:

```
R = zeros(N_x);
delta_n = 0.003 %difference between the high and low refractive index

flag = 0;
c = 0; % this is strength of randomness in the lattice refractive index
sqwv = zeros(N_x,1); %this matrix is pretty much the $x_j$ matrix which is later assigned to the diagonal of the R matrix
del_c = 0;
del_mat = [];

if c == 0
    for i = 1:N_x
        del_mat(i) = del_c;
        if flag == 0
            sqwv(i) = 1.46^2-n_r^2+del_c;
        elseif flag == 1
            sqwv(i) = 1.463^2-n_r^2+del_c;
    
        end
        if rem(i,1) == 0    
            del_c = c*delta_n*rand(); %disorderness parameter for the refractive index when I want to generate a disorder in lattice
            if flag == 0
                flag = 1;
            elseif flag == 1
                flag = 0;
            end
        end
    
    end
    
    
    figure();
    plot(x,sqwv);
    
    
    for i = 1:N_x
        R(i,i) = sqwv(i);
    end
end
```

For $c = 0$, I get $R$ matrix(lattice) of form:

[image]

Now I define my input signal which is a gaussian beam, and it's derivative:

```
psi = exp(-(x/W0).^2);
psi = transpose(psi); %transposed the input gaussian beam for consistent matrix multplication later in the code

psi_der = diag(zeros(N_x));

mat_new(1,:) = psi./max(psi); % mat_new matrix is two by two matrix that stores the output. I have assigned the first row to be the input signal
```

Now I run the main loop across $N_z$ i.e. the number of lattice points in z-direction

```
for i = 1:N_z-1
    

    if c~=0
        for i = 1:N_x
            del_mat(i) = del_c;
            if flag == 0
                sqwv(i) = 1.46^2-n_r^2+del_c;
            elseif flag == 1
                sqwv(i) = 1.463^2-n_r^2+del_c;

            end
            if rem(i,1) == 0    
                del_c = c*delta_n*rand();
                if flag == 0
                    flag = 1;
                elseif flag == 1
                    flag = 0;
                end
            end

        end
        R = diag(sqwv);
   
    
        
    
        eta = P_11*psi+P_12*psi_der;
        eta_der = P_21*psi+P_22*psi_der;

        QP_11 = eta*delta_z;
        QP_21 = -(k_0^2)*R*(normalize(eta_der))*delta_z;
        

        psi_new = P_11*QP_11 + P_21*QP_21;
        psi_der_new = P_21*QP_11+P_22*QP_21;

        psi = psi_new;
        psi_der = psi_der_new;   
        mat_new(i+1,:) = psi_new;
        %mat_new(i,:) = psi_new;
    end
    if c==0
        eta = P_11*psi+P_12*psi_der;
        eta_der = P_21*psi+P_22*psi_der;

        QP_11 = eta*delta_z;
        QP_21 = -(k_0^2)*R*(normalize(eta_der))*delta_z;
       

        psi_new = P_11*QP_11 + P_21*QP_21;
        psi_der_new = P_21*QP_11+P_22*QP_21;

        psi = psi_new;
        psi_der = psi_der_new;   
        mat_new(i+1,:) = psi_new;

    end

end
```

Notice that there is conditional for c~=0 and $c=0$. **That is done so that when I require a disordered lattice (i.e. c~= 0), $R$ matrix is calculated for every iteration to introduce disorder throughout the system.** Otherwise, $R$ matrix calculated above is used. The multplications in the loop are as follows:
$$
P\Phi(z) = \begin{bmatrix}
            P_{11} \psi + P_{12} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z} \\
            P_{21} \psi + P_{22} \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial z}
       \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
                            \xi \\
                            \frac{d \xi}{d z}
                        \end{bmatrix}
$$

then,
$$
Q(z)\{P\Phi(z)\{ = \begin{bmatrix}
                   \xi \Delta z \\
                   -k_0^2 R(z) \frac{d\xi}{dz} \Delta z
                \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, this matrix is multiplied with $P$ matrix again and the next step of propagtion is obtained ($\phi(z+\Delta z) = PQP \phi(z)$). Then I assign it to the mat_new matrix every iteration and then finally mesh plot the mat_new matrix.

```
mat_new = (abs(mat_new).^2)./max(abs(mat_new).^2);%to only plot the absolute values
figure();
mesh(mat_new);
xlabel("x-axis");
ylabel("z-axis");
zlabel("Intensity");
colormap default;
colorbar;
```

For c=0 i.e. ordered lattice, I am getting a result which is somewhat okay:

[image]

I am not sure why the signal is spread out so much in the beginning (the parallel yellow lines) even though the input signal is a gaussian beam and such a spread is unexpected.

For c not eqaul to zero, there is the expected localization but it is random, and broken. It should be concentrated at the centre, but there extra lines in the lattice besides that.

[image]

Please help me figure out what am I doing wrong. It would be helpful to know how to implement the $R$ matrix properly. Or how to generate a disordered lattice.